# How to use NSWindowController?

Tags: cocoa, nswindowcontroller

I'm looking in to using `NSWindowController` and I just can't think how to get it working. How do I start using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to answer this question without knowing what you're trying to do.  However, if you are writing a document-based application, an NSWindowController is automatically created for each window you create, so you don't need to create one specially.

The way I use NSWindowController is I create a different subclass for each type of window in my application.  For example, I might have a 3D application with an AppWireframeWindowController and an AppPreviewWindowController.  Each subclass automatically loads the correct nib file, and has code that hooks the document's data to the views in the nib.

Comment: No, an NSWindowController is not automatically created for each window you create. It is automatically created for each *document*, but if you directly create a window, or load a nib with a window in it, neither action will create a window controller.

Comment: Is NSWindowController used with using NSDocument?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboards you can connect an NSWindowController subclass up in IB. Otherwise if you are using nibs and have just the default template for a Mac Cocoa app then you may need to make it in code or just use a subclass of NSWindow.

Otherwise you can create a new NSWindowController and check the 'Also create XIB file for user interface' and it will give you the nib and also the NSWindowController subclass. It is basically a new nib where 'File's Owner' is your NSWindowController and the Window is the .window object inside the NSWindowController and the delegate is also pointed there.

You may be able to modify that.