# Transition between windows in OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, transition, nswindowcontroller, nsviewcontroller

I am going to make an OS X application with several views and windows.

It has several screens - splash, login/register and the main screen(and so on).

I tried to use NSWindowControllers. However, it's so complex to use and I'm confused.

What is the best experience in the view/window transitions?

Comment: Are your windows all in the same xib file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115257/how-to-use-nswindowcontroller
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683349/nswindowcontroller-clarification-of-understanding will help you out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main pattern I use is the follow:

- Create a `New File` `User Interface` `Window` and save it as `nameYouLike`
- Create a `New File` `Cocoa` `Objective-C class` of `NSWindowController` subclass and save is as `nameYouLikeDelegate`
- Go to nameYouLike NSWindow and change it's `File's Owner` `Class` to `nameYouLikeDelegate`
- Connect `window` and other objects you need of xib with an `IBOutlet` to `nameYouLikeDelegate.h`
- In some init/show method do this:

  ```
  - (void)showWindow {
      if (!self.window) {
          [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"nameYouLike" owner:self];
      }

      [self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
  }
  ```
- Save reference in some way (f.e. in `AppDelegate` or `NSWindowController` of another window):

  ```
  nameYouLikeDelegate *fNameYouLikeDelegate;
  ```
- Now when you need to create your window you use:

  ```
  fNameYouLikeDelegate = [[nameYouLikeDelegate alloc] init];
  ```
- And to show it:

  ```
  [fNameYouLikeDelegate showWindow];
  ```

Comment: doesn't work for me. But I created class first and then chose "also create xib"

Answer (score 1):

How would you like to transition?
It's probably unnecessary to transition between windows in your case.
Better you make a NSViewController and transition between the subviews of the window.
You should check out the basics of Cocoa.

You can then use the animator property of the views.

```
[[self.view animator] setAlphaValue:0.0];
```